# jQuery Mobile panel width

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

In the new jQuery mobile there is a new panel option. I have implemented this and it works, but I would like to customize the width of the panel. The standard width is 272px, which is a bit much for my use. I have tried using the

```
.ui-panel{width:150px;}
```

CSS selector, but this simply resizes the contents of the panel. The panel itself stays visible and remains the same width. Using the inspectors in firefox and chrome I have not been able to find the correct div responsible for this panel. Could anybody help me find a way to resize the panel in the correct manner?

Comment: Have you checked encapsulating div's or any elements within the panel? You could always try !important. The code you have posted seems like it should work, which leads me to believe there is something wrong somewhere else in the code.

Comment: Seems we need some framework level hack

Comment: Looking over documentation, I think the flaw is another typo, that we should be referencing .ui-panel, not ui.panel, in the css file. If that's correct, I'll revise my answer to reflect it....

Comment: this is from documentation `Panels have a fixed width of 17em (272 pixels) which is narrow enough to still show some of the page contents when open to make clicking out to close easy, while still looking good on wider tablet or desktop screens. The styles to set widths on panels are fairly complex but these can be overridden with CSS as needed.`

Comment: Sorry, my bad for the typo!. I've tried several div's. I also read the same sentence in the documentation, and was mystified by it. Basically it says it's hard but possible and then gives no hint whatsoever how to achieve it.

Comment: using jquery mobile 1.4.5, the originally suggested solution works - just setting a width for .ui-panel gives the sizing behaviour that is expected.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I figured it out! It's not that complex, really. I myself am just using structure.css but if you're using other CSS files there MAY be more to customize. Anyway...

Using your favorite editor, do a find & replace for "17em" and replace that with the value you actually want. There's styling for left panels and styling for right panels. I wouldn't rush through this whole process as there could be an unrelated "17em" here or there. It just takes a minute...

It's a simple answer but I'm happy with myself :p

Comment: That worked! :) I count a total of 5 CSS classes in which I had to change the attribute from 17em to my new value. Seems a bit complicated for something that in my opinion should be quite easy! But thanks for you answer :), much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 11):

I had same issue myself and followed tylerl's advice to replace 17em with the width I needed. Which worked well, except for the fact that I was using google cdn to load css, so I could not change it directly and in general I am not a big fan of changing library code.

So playing around with it a little I came up with this code for redefining default jquery mobile's css https://gist.github.com/geekdevs/5433246

You can configure width for left and right sidebars separately. This is LESS code, but simply replacing @left-sidebar-width and @right-sidebar-width with the width you need will make it work for plain CSS as well.

Comment: Thanks Pavel! Excellent solution :). I don't like editing library code  either, but in this case sadly I had no choice. But this should definitely help! :)

Answer (score 5):

They show how to change the panel width in this demo: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0/docs/examples/panels/panel-styling.html

Comment: I tried that too, but the same thing happens, the listview in the panel is resized, and some sort of "no-mans land" is created between the listview and the main page contents

Answer (score 2):

I didn't wanted to make modifications to the library css file so I tried above patches but none of them worked on **jquery mobile 1.4.1**

I had to add few more styling to get it to work.

Here is my modified css. (replace 10em and 15 em with your left and right size respectively)

```
.ui-panel {
    width: 10em;
}

.ui-panel.ui-panel-position-right {
    width: 15em;
}

.ui-panel.ui-panel-closed {
    width: 0;
}

.ui-panel-animate.ui-panel-position-left.ui-panel-display-overlay, .ui-panel-animate.ui-panel-position-left.ui-panel-display-push {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-10em, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(-10em, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-10em, 0, 0)
}

.ui-panel-animate.ui-panel-position-right.ui-panel-display-overlay, .ui-panel-animate.ui-panel-position-right.ui-panel-display-push {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(15em, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(15em, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(15em, 0, 0)
}

.ui-panel-animate.ui-panel-content-fixed-toolbar-position-left.ui-panel-content-fixed-toolbar-open.ui-panel-content-fixed-toolbar-display-reveal, .ui-panel-animate.ui-panel-content-fixed-toolbar-position-left.ui-panel-content-fixed-toolbar-open.ui-panel-content-fixed-toolbar-display-push, .ui-panel-animate.ui-panel-content-wrap-position-left.ui-panel-content-wrap-open.ui-panel-content-wrap-display-reveal, .ui-panel-animate.ui-panel-content-wrap-position-left.ui-panel-content-wrap-open.ui-panel-content-wrap-display-push {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(10em, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(10em, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(10em, 0, 0)
}

.ui-panel-animate.ui-panel-page-content-position-left{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(10em, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(10em, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(10em, 0, 0);
}

.ui-panel-animate.ui-panel-content-fixed-toolbar-position-right.ui-panel-content-fixed-toolbar-open.ui-panel-content-fixed-toolbar-display-reveal, .ui-panel-animate.ui-panel-content-fixed-toolbar-position-right.ui-panel-content-fixed-toolbar-open.ui-panel-content-fixed-toolbar-display-push, .ui-panel-animate.ui-panel-content-wrap-position-right.ui-panel-content-wrap-open.ui-panel-content-wrap-display-reveal, .ui-panel-animate.ui-panel-content-wrap-position-right.ui-panel-content-wrap-open.ui-panel-content-wrap-display-push {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-15em, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(-15em, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-15em, 0, 0)
}
```

Comment: For what it's worth, this seems to still work perfectly in **jQM 1.4.5**. At least, I haven't had any issues yet...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to globally edit the size, add this to your custom css adding IDs where necessary, changing **23em** to your desired width:

**Note:** This is only for the left side.

```
.ui-panel {
    width: 23em;
}
.ui-panel-position-left {
    left: -23em;
}
/* positioning: content wrap, fixed toolbars and dismiss */
/* panel left open */
.ui-panel-content-fixed-toolbar-position-left.ui-panel-content-fixed-toolbar-open,
.ui-panel-content-wrap-position-left.ui-panel-content-wrap-open,
.ui-panel-dismiss-position-left.ui-panel-dismiss-open {
    left: 23em;
    right: -23em;
}
/* animated: panel left open (for reveal and push) */
.ui-panel-animate.ui-panel-content-fixed-toolbar-position-left.ui-panel-content-fixed-toolbar-open.ui-panel-content-fixed-toolbar-display-reveal,
.ui-panel-animate.ui-panel-content-fixed-toolbar-position-left.ui-panel-content-fixed-toolbar-open.ui-panel-content-fixed-toolbar-display-push,
.ui-panel-animate.ui-panel-content-wrap-position-left.ui-panel-content-wrap-open.ui-panel-content-wrap-display-reveal,
.ui-panel-animate.ui-panel-content-wrap-position-left.ui-panel-content-wrap-open.ui-panel-content-wrap-display-push {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(23em,0,0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(23em,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(23em,0,0);
}
```

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately it does not work in jquery mobile 1.4.1

Answer (score 0):

I think you've made a typo. Try

```
.ui-panel { width: 150px; }
```

or if you're issuing that inline, perhaps

```
<panel style="width: 150px;">
```

Of course, new as I am to jquery, I could be wrong.

Comment: Typo, that's what I meant with my original post. That only resizes the contents of the panel, rather than the actual panel

Comment: The docs say "The styles to set widths on panels are fairly complex but these can be overridden with CSS as needed." Unfortunately, it does not explain the complexities.... Harrumph. http://api.jquerymobile.com/panel/

Answer (score 0):

you need to put the following css (left panel)

```
.ui-panel{
    width: 150px!important;
}

.ui-panel-animate.ui-panel-page-content-position-left {

    transform: translate3d(150px,0,0) !important;
}
```