# How alter width of jQuery Mobile Panel

Tags: jquery-mobile, panel

I have a Panel in jQM 1.3.1 working on a page but I need to increase its width.  I have applied this CSS:

```
.ui-pannel-inner {
    width: 25em;
}
```

which does increase the width "visually" so the Panel is now "wide", but the framework creates a `<div class="ui-panel-dismiss ui-panel-dismiss-position-right ui-panel-dismiss-display-push ui-panel-dismiss-open" data-panelid="PanelOptions"></div>` whose width is apparently defined based on the default Panel width.  This `<div>` serves as the "clickable" area that closes the Panel.  Normally, this area would exactly match the area of the page not covered by the Panel but it actually covers of the Panel as well.  As a result, (this is a "right side" Panel) if I click in the Panel near it's left edge (to click on, say, a radio button) I will click in the area covered by the `<div class="ui-panel-dismiss...` and the Panel closes.  That is, `<div class="ui-panel-dismiss` covers part of the left side of the Panel.

I know I can add `data-dismissible="false"` to the <`div data-role="panel" ...` tag to prevent this behavior but then I lose the ability to close the Panel by clicking on the page.

I have tried the suggestions presented @ [jQuery Mobile panel width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15225960/jquery-mobile-panel-width) and they both do alter the "visible" panel width but neither one deals with the fact that `<div class="ui-panel-dismiss...` is still overlapping the additional width of the Panel.

How do I "correctly" alter the width of the Panel so that I don't have to use `-dismissible="false"`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing exactly the same issue as mentioned in the question. 
So after setting the with of the panel I used the below to override the css property of the panel so that it does not close.

```
.ui-panel-dismiss-position-right.ui-panel-dismiss-open {
left: -20em!important;
right: 20em!important; }
```

The default is set to left:-17em and right:17em. You can increase the value as per the width you have set and check whether Panel is closing or not.

Hope this helps.

Comment: For anyone else who is wondering why the sample code on the 1.4.5 demos doesn't work as expected, it is necessary to add `!important` to override the framework defaults.

Answer (score 0):

you can point the position of dismiss panel by override ui-panel-dismiss-position-left like this

```
 .ui-panel-dismiss-position-left{
     left: -240px;
     right: 240px;
 }
```

or you can dynamically modify the position after the panel was opened.

see http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/examples/panels/panel-styling.html#&ui-state=dialog

Answer (score 0):

just add to your head section:

```
  <style>
    .ui-panel-dismiss-open.ui-panel-dismiss-position-left { left: 356px !important }
  </style>
```

worked for me with jQuery Mobile 1.4.5