# when i change jquerymobile panel width after clicking close button it closes panel with a non desired effect

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-collapsible

I wanted to change the width of **.ui-panel** for my mobile interface so i did a change inside my media query like this (in css)

```
.ui-panel{width: 310px !important}
```

But now when i close it. It shows a hitch when it reach to the point where it ends for 17em

I tried this solution from here: [jQuery Mobile panel width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15225960/jquery-mobile-panel-width)

any suggestions ?

Comment: is it dismissible or not? overlay, push or reveal? left or right?

Answer (score 1):

When change width of `overlay` or `push` panel, you also have to update `translate3d` animation property to match the width. By default panel's width is `17em`, and the default animation `x` position is `-17em`.

```css
/* left panel - overlay and push */
.ui-panel-animate.ui-panel-position-left.ui-panel-display-overlay,
.ui-panel-animate.ui-panel-position-left.ui-panel-display-push {
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-310px,0,0);
     -moz-transform: translate3d(-310px,0,0);
          transform: translate3d(-310px,0,0);
}

/* right panel - overlay and push */
.ui-panel-animate.ui-panel-position-right.ui-panel-display-overlay,
.ui-panel-animate.ui-panel-position-right.ui-panel-display-push {
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-310px,0,0);
     -moz-transform: translate3d(-310px,0,0);
          transform: translate3d(-310px,0,0);
}
```